# Validating From using AJAX and jQuery without sending data to another file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, validation

my problem is - for now - not about specific code but more about basic understanding - I think.

I want to create a formular and use the data without refreshing the page, so that brings me to AJAX.

Now do I always have to create a seperate file that works with the data that AJAX sends? Can't I just "grab" the data and work with it on the same page?

I think I missunderstood some basic concepts.

I thought about something like this:

```
<form id="load_filters_form">
  ..
</form>

<?php
  var_dump($_GET); // values from <form>
?>

<!-- AJAX, jQuery -->
<script>
  $("#load_filters_form").submit(function(event){

    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({

      type: 'get',
      data: $(this).serialize()
      success: function() {
        $("#load_filters_form")[0].reset(); 
      }

    });

  });
</script>
```

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you're asking.  You can use your data any way that you like.  What exactly isn't working?  If your validation logic is on this page then you can use that logic without having to make an AJAX request.  (Note: You shouldn't implicitly trust *any* client-side validation and should still validate server-side before committing to any action from this data.)

Comment: What I try to achieve is that I dont have to reload the page, still have the data though. Usually I would send the form to the same page but that also reloads it, right?

Comment: If you're using AJAX then the current visible page isn't reloaded.  AJAX just makes a request to the server in the background (in code) and handles the response in code.  I recommend you look up some examples and tutorials on AJAX to get a demonstrable understanding on what it's doing.

Comment: Yes and I want to handle the result on the same page. Isn't that possible?

Answer (score 0):

What you're proposing is certainly possible, it's exactly how AJAX works.  You make an AJAX request from JavaScript code, sending any data the server-side code will need, and handle the response from the server in your JavaScript code.

The problem with what you're proposing is that you're making it unnecessarily complex for yourself.  Consider what your code in the question would return to the JavaScript code in the AJAX response.  It returns *an entire HTML page*, most of which is already on the client.

Why re-transmit all of that data that the client already has?  Why have code on the client to parse out the data it's looking for from all of the unnecessary markup around that data?

Keep your operations simple.  If you need a server-side operation which receives data, performs logic, and returns a result then create an operation which does exactly that.  Call that operation in AJAX and use the resulting *data*.

Now maybe that response is structured JSON data, which your client-side code can read and update the UI accordingly.  Or maybe that response is raw HTML (not an *entire page* but perhaps a single `<div>` or any kind of container which presents an updated version of a section of the page), which your client-side code can swap into the UI directly.

The AJAX interactions with the server should generally be light.  If you're intentionally re-loading the entire page in an AJAX operation then, well, why use AJAX in the first place?  The point is to send to the server only the data it needs, and receive back from the server only the data you need.  For example, if all you need is to update a list of records displayed on the page then you don't need the whole page or even the HTML table of records, you just need the records.  JSON is useful for exactly that, returning structured data and only structured data to the client.  Then the client-side code can render that data into the structure of the page.

Answer (score 0):

> Now do I always have to create a separate file that works with the data that AJAX sends?

Yes and no. You may choose not to have a specific file which your ajax is pulling, but you do need some sort of Routing and Controller relationship as most frameworks build it.

You could in theory create a request to self (the same page) but that's bad logic. You are going to mix backend logic with frontend and will get messy - very quickly. You really need to separate all three elements,

- PHP takes the data and process it
- JavaScript takes the data and displays it
- Your html should be code free; Just a pretty finalized product.

The best design pattern is to separate those files in their proper environment.

> Can't I just "grab" the data and work with it on the same page?

Not really, at least not consistently. You also have to keep in mind it's a potential issue in attempting to serve two separate contents from the same route/file:

```php
if ajax 
// do something
else
// do the other thing
```

Ajax does not want fully rendered HTML files, it takes too long; it's best to serve JSON objects/arrays which will be rendered in your frontend via JavaScript; which was also used to make the request - in the user's browser without the latency caused by their network or your server.

There's no sure way of knowing which request is what since no data from the client is trustworthy, including HTTP headers; they are easy to fake and could potentially lead to security/unwanted results.

Thus, the best solutions is to have a foreign file which you would make the requests to, instead of doing it from itself.